# facebook scrape error regarding og:image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Please note that I am far from being proficient in HTML so I might be doing something silly. Also I am posting this question because although I found other questions about the same topic, none of them addressed the exact problem I am having. Thanks.

I am trying to use the Open Graph properties in the meta-data of my blog to control which image facebook shows, but facebook claims that there is a problem with my image.

Here is the metadata I have added inside the `<header/>` tag:

```
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="Salud, cuerpo, mente y dieta" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="Que tu alimento sea tu medicina y la medicina tu alimento - Aristóteles de Cos" />
<meta content='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-9eH_b6ILSic/VwneIrX1hZI/AAAAAAAAUR4/8t-krO2wqzAT90Rrv3PQ-rwB1E09IVt3g/s1600-r/salud_cuerpo_mente_dieta_612x327.PNG' property='og:image'/>
```

When I use facebook's [Open Graph Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) and point it to my blog (saludcuerpodieta.blogspot.ca), this is the problem I find:

```
og:image could not be downloaded or is too small
og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook. Image 'http://poweredbygreensmoothies.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/green-smoothie-jars-1.jpg' will be used instead. Consult http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler for more troubleshooting tips.
```

I read several things, including facebook's guidelines and best practices, where they say that the image has to be bigger than 600x315. Mine is 612x327, so it should work.

I have found that if I replace the image I want with the image facebook falls back to, things work as expected. That image is 2034x1296. Now, the problem with making my image that big, is that it is the header of my blog and it would not look good having the image that big (in fact, I would like the image to be even smaller than 600x315, but I made it bigger because of the troubleshooting tips I read).

Can you help me, please? What I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention one thing, sorry. Also I have problems with the **description**. While the debugger sees the description, if I copy paste the URL of the blog in facebook it shows a different description.

Comment: You say you are putting <meta> elements in the <header> element, but was that a typo? Metas should go in the <head>, not the <header>.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo, sorry

Answer (score 0):

If Facebook tried to reach the image URL and it was invalid, unreachable, etc, the URL is cached as being an invalid image -

Try changing the filename if you're sure the image you're trying to use is reachable and valid (e.g. add a cache busting parameter to the og:image value or rename the file)